# Is there a way to use a tensor as an input to functions such as tf.reshape or tf.constant

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use a tensor as a shape input to another tensorflow function. Is there any way to get this to work?

Example

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])

b = tf.size(a)

c = tf.constant([b,1])

d = tf.reshape(a, [b,1])

sess = tf.Session()

print sess.run([b,c])
```

Neither of the above will work, as tensorflow interprets the input dimensions as a list of tensors and gives an error, the bottom line of which is:

```
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

I assume a work-around would be to open a session, evaluate 'b' to get a numpy float, and convert this to an integer, but was hoping to avoid this if possible.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `a.get_shape()` which can get results **outside** of a session (it will give the **inferred shape**):

```
a = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5])
b = a. get_shape().as_list()[0]
d = tf.reshape(a, [b, 1])
```

You could also use `-1` with `tf.reshape`, it will keep the total size constant.

```
d = tf.reshape(a, [-1, 1])
```